# distanceFilter property of CLLocationManager is not working properly

Tags: iphone, location, distance, cllocationmanager

I am using CLLocationManager in my application.
I am using following code for initialize CLLocationManger.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[self.locationManager setDelegate:self];

[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:10.0];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I have set distanceFilter as a 10.0 meter.
Now I am not moving my device (it's still on one location).
but after sometimes the delegate of CLLocationManger is automatically called.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
     NSLog(@"Locations : %@", locations);
  }
```

I want to get new location if my device is moving around 10 meters otherwise not.

So, pls tell me how to use this distanceFilter property and get new location.

Comment: Did you found problem why you was getting location updates even without moving 10 meters? I have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is how GPS works, you are standing still, probaly sitting on your desk near the window with usually horrible GPS signal.

GPS does not know that you are not moving, especially when the signal is bad, it looks like you moved. Therfore you get an event. If you want to do it better, then you have to filter yourself, and do not rely of apples distance filter.

This then may work better for your special application.