# Minimum distance of distanceFilter(CLLocationManager)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-location

```swift
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.distanceFilter = 1
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

I wanted to set the distance of distanceFilter 1 meter.
I don't think it works properly. **I wonder the minimum distance of the distanceFilter**

---

Another thing!

[distanceFilter property of CLLocationManager is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608178/distancefilter-property-of-cllocationmanager-is-not-working-properly)

I saw this page and I think the guy says there is another thing which is better than distanceFilter. **What is it?**

I am on a bus and the latitude and longtitude changes fast. But I am not sure that they changes every meter the bus moves.

Comment: How exactly does it not work properly?

Comment: The `distanceFilter` states the the location update will only be sent if the new location is at least that distance from the previous location. So setting it to a small value means nothing will be filtered while moving on a bus.

Comment: "the guy says there is another thing which is better than `distanceFilter`" Are you referring to "then you have to filter yourself"? What don't you understand about it. They are saying you should filter the location updates yourself, based on your own needs.

Comment: Gps-based location updates are delivered about once per second. The accuracy of a GPS-based location is typically about 10m (check the `horizontalAccuracy` property of the location you receive), so even if you aren't moving you may get  an update of less than 10m simply due to noise

Comment: @HangarRash As you said, even a centimeter movement will make the difference from the previous location. I don't get it.

Comment: @Sweeper What is the meaning of filtering the location updates yourself? and how?

Comment: @Paulw11 You are meaning iPhone's GPS? or most of the GPS device?

Comment: @YMB If the next location update is only 1cm then that is less than your filter of 1m so you won't get that location update. Not with the code you posted. You are specifically saying you don't want such small changes. Also keep in mind that you won't ever get such tiny changes anyway since GPS is not that precise.

Comment: I mean the phone's GPS, since that is what we are talking about here.

Comment: What I meant was, you can come up with an algorithm yourself, to determine which location updates you should ignore.

Answer (score 2):

> But I am not sure that they changes every meter the bus moves.

`distanceFilter` does not mean "update every n meters".

`distanceFilter`, as its name suggests, is a *filter*. Location updates come in at some rate, and `distanceFilter` removes (i.e. filters out) some of them, depending on how far they are from the previous update. This does not control *when* the updates are generated. Updates are generated by the GPS on the device, and it can do that however often it wants.

To get the most updates, you would not filter out anything. If you don't set `distanceFilter`, that is how `CLLocationManager` would behave. The default value of `distanceFilter` is [`kCLDistanceFilterNone`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/kcldistancefilternone), so you can also use that if you want.

Running on the simulator, I get location updates about every second. If you want updates even more frequently than that, you technically can call `locationManager.requestLocation()` repeatedly.

```
let lm = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    lm.delegate = self
    lm.requestLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // here you can check if the updated locations are far enough apart from the previous update

    print("Updated!")
    // after receiving a location, request again
    lm.requestLocation()
}
```

That said, this will repeatedly start and stop location services. I'm not sure if Apple would like that.